# PlistBuddy on Windows

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, info.plist, plistbuddy

I’m in the process of moving our Xamarin build infrastructure to be Windows based and I’ve hit a problem in that our build scripts currently use PlistBuddy to read from and write to the Info.plist file of an app.

Obviously PlistBuddy won’t run on Windows.

Has anyone seen any other solution for interacting with Plist files on Windows? I’ve seen a few that use a GUI but we would need this to have a CLI.

Comment: Why do you need PlistBuddy on Windows? Your CI needs a macOS with installed iOS-SDK to create and sign the ipa anyways.

Comment: It does but that's all handled through Visual Studio and MSBuild it doesn't mean the build scripts run on an OS X box.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the Build Agent to run arbitrary commands on the Mac via tying into any generic `Task/Target`(You can look in the Xamarin.iOS `.targets` files for a better idea here) that runs across the SSH connection. This is currently available in another method by using the `<Exec>` Task with a `SessionId` of your `$(BuildSessionId)`. Here's an example of how you might do this:

```
<Exec Command="..." SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" />
```

If the `SessionId` is null/empty, then that means we are not connected to the Mac. If it's not null/empty, then we are connected to the Mac.

We can then force this condition to always run on the Mac via:

```
<Exec Command="..." SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" Condition=" '$(BuildSessionId)' != '' " />
```

Please note that the following built-in tasks are exposed for remote execution:

- Copy
- Delete
- Exec
- MakeDir
- Move
- RemoveDir
- Touch

Source: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Core/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets#L74-L80

You can then invoke the `PlistBuddy` Command via this method.

**EX:**

```
  <Target Name="_SayGoodbye">
    <Exec Command="plistbuddy ..." SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" Condition=" '$(BuildSessionId)' != '' "/>
  </Target>
```

If you wanted to go about a `MSBuild` custom Task way, You can see examples of previous built Tasks here:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/tree/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Core/Tasks

**EX** Plist in Use:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Core/Tasks/MTouchTaskBase.cs#L608

**EX** Tests with Plist:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/tree/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/msbuild/tests/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Tests/TaskTests/GeneratePlistTaskTests

This is more of a MSBuild customization at this point, but it's definitely possible to do what you're trying to do using these items.